# Access to MySQL with R using a pre 4.1.1 authentication protocol

Tags: mysql, database, r, plot, protocols

I need to access to a MySQL remote server, and I want to do this with the R software.

I set up the connection parameter but I can't access. I use this code:

```
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
library(RMySQL)
# open the connection using user, passsword, etc., as
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="user", password="psw",
dbname="NameDB", host="webhosting", port=3306)
```

And I receive this error:

```
Error in mysqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
RS-DBI driver: (Failed to connect to database: Error: Connection using old (pre-4.1.1)
authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)
```

I tried to connect to the database with the MySQL workbench, and it's working only if I select the option: "use the old authentication protocol". 
Hence I know that it is what I need to activate in my connection, also using R. However I don't know how to do this! I tried to disable "secure_auth" but dbConnect does not have that parameter.

How can I change the authorization? Thanks in advance!

P.s.: I can't upgrade the server password to make it compatible with post-4.1.1 protocol.

Comment: Don't you need the server's ip to connect? This is what i've been using and works but the server is in the local lan. So i don't know if it would help you. 
```con <- dbConnect("MySQL", user = "username", dbname = "DatabaseName", host = "192.168.1.4", password = "yourpassword")```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to connect to MySQL with [RJDBC](https://www.rforge.net/RJDBC/) instead - it will connect with the JDBC driver under the covers, which apparently will allow [old-style authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443827/what-jdbc-property-corresponds-to-mysql-command-lines-skip-secure-auth-opti).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the DB, you can Clone the remote DB to a local one using MySQL Workbench. Then it's just a local connection, and you can disable/control authentication on it.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to MySQL with R using a pre-4.1.1 authentication protocol, you need to add a parameter to the `dbConnect()` function called `useLegacyAuth`. This parameter should be set to TRUE to enable the old authentication protocol.

```
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
library(RMySQL)
# open the connection using user, password, etc., as
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="user", password="psw",
dbname="NameDB", host="webhosting", port=3306, useLegacyAuth=TRUE)
```