# What JDBC property corresponds to mysql command line's "--skip-secure-auth" option?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, command-line-arguments

I have one legacy database which needs to be connected like this from command prompt

```
mysql --uUserName -hHostName -pPassword -P3307 -A Schema --skip-secure-auth
```

How do I specify the same in JDBC properties `--skip-secure-auth`

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://HostName:3307/Schema
jdbc.user=UserName
jdbc.password=Password
jdbc.maxConnections=5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`--skip-secure-auth`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_secure-auth) allows the use of the old, pre-4.1 password hashing method. This obsolete authentication mechanism is handled by a plugin known as [`mysql_old_password`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_secure-auth).

[According to the Connector/J manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), it is *not* disabled by default (read about the `disabledAuthenticationPlugins` option), so I suppose the default behaviour is to allow such connections (i.e. equivalent to `mysql --skip-secure-auth`).

Comment: even i observed the same. it doesn't need any optional argument passed. I was facing issue with some other during connection, i though this could be the culprit :)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has still the same problem as OP of MySQL using older password hashing method, then the recommended practice is to change the passwords as [pointed here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-hashing.html).

If at the moment the above is not possible and you just want to make your JDBC connector connect to MySQL the old not so secure way, then way to do it in context.xml file is

```
authenticationPlugins="com.mysql.jdbc.authentication.MysqlOldPasswordPlugin"
```

Not sure what is the corresponding JDBC syntax.

Since mysql-connector-java-5.1.19 (latest one I have is 5.1.23) JAR, the default authentication is `com.mysql.jdbc.authentication.MysqlNativePasswordPlugin`, so you are basically changing the authentication mode from the default to older one through the above mentioned snippet.